# Custom Taxonomies not showing

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom post type called Products, and each product has a custom category of either Commercial, Residential or Retail. When visiting the following URL: `http://176.67.171.11/airvent/product/aquaguard/` you can see the list of categories on the left hand side. Click on and you will get an archive page of all the regular blog posts instead of the custom post types posts for that category.
I have added archive-product.php but it doesn't seem to pull it in?

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

**My Code:** (from [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/cjRRbM11))

```
register_taxonomy( 'product_range_cat', 
    array('product'), 
    array('hierarchical' => true,                  
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Product Categories', 'bonestheme' ), 
            'singular_name' => __( 'Product Category', 'bonestheme' ), 
            'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Product Categories', 'bonestheme' ), 
            'all_items' => __( 'All Product Categories', 'bonestheme' ), 
            'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Product Category', 'bonestheme' ), 
            'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Product Category:', 'bonestheme' ),
            'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Product Category', 'bonestheme' ), 
            'update_item' => __( 'Update Product Category', 'bonestheme' ), 
            'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Product Category', 'bonestheme' ), 
            'new_item_name' => __( 'New Product Category Name', 'bonestheme' ) 
        ),
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'product-category' ),
    )
);
```

Comment: please post the code associated with your custom taxonomies.

Comment: Here's a pastebin of the code: http://pastebin.com/cjRRbM11

Comment: did you try to switching the the permalinks back to default and then back to your current settings aka permalink cycling?

Comment: It's possible that archive-product.php will make it look for a CATEGORY named product, so try taxonomy-product.php instead. (This is a stab in the dark)

Comment: I tried resetting the permalinks, and tried creating a taxonomy-product.php template, neither worked. my body class says the following: <body class="archive tax-product_range_cat term-commercial term-5 logged-in">

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem, it was a snippet I found that excluded the product category type from loop.php:

`<?php query_posts($query_string . '&cat=-4'); //Custom query to exclude category/ies ?>`

I still can't figure out why it won't call archive-product.php though?

Thanks for your help.